# Quoting lines of a file in Linux

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to enclose each line of a file in single quotes and append `,` at the end of each line.

I have tried,

```
sed 's/^*$/\'&\',/g' filename
```

I have also tried,

```
sed 's/^/'/;s/$/',/'  filename
```

both don't seem to help.Please advise.

Comment: Based on your solution : `sed "s/^/'/; s/$/',/" file` (use double quotes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

```
sed "s/.*/'&',/" file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v q="'" '{$0= q $0 q ","}1' input
'line one',
'line two',
'line three',
```

Using `awk`: 1. Enclosing the whole line between single quotes. 2. Adding comma at the end of each line.

Comment: or with hex values: `awk '$0="\x27" $0 "\x27,"' file`

Answer (score 0):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/^|$/,"'"'"'")' file
'line one'
'line two'
'line three'
```

ie. the `'` is double-quoted `"` `'` `"` and that is single-quoted `'` `"` `'` `"` `'` and again double-quoted in the `gsub` `"` `'` `"` `'` `"` `'` `"`. No, I'm not kidding.